# Null error when assigning value to property

Tags: c#, oop

Trying to create a custom object that will allow me to pickup errors in the records.

```
public class gridIntegerField
{
    private int value;
    private bool isValid;
    private string message;



    public int Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return isValid; }
        set { isValid = value; }
    }
    public string Message
    {
        get { return message; }
        set { message = value; }
    }


}

public class gridRecord    
{
    private gridIntegerField printRun;

    public gridIntegerField PrintRun
    {
      get { return printRun; }
      set { printRun = value; }
    }

}
```

when creating object and trying to set the values i get the folowing error...

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XML- Console.exe

Code for creating object...

```
gridRecord spr = new gridRecord();
spr.PrintRun.Value = 200;
spr.PrintRun.IsValid = true;
spr.PrintRun.Message = "No Errors";

Console.WriteLine(spr.PrintRun.Value.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(spr.PrintRun.IsValid.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(spr.PrintRun.Message.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

the error happens at this line of code

```
spr.PrintRun.Value = 200;
```

Comment: spr.PrintRun=new gridIntegerField() add before assign value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you do not instantiate the `printRun` field after `gridRecord` instantiating.

You can do it in the constructor method.

```
public class gridRecord    
{
    private gridIntegerField printRun;

    public gridIntegerField PrintRun
    {
      get { return printRun; }
      set { printRun = value; }
    }

    //Add a constructor method
    public gridRecord()
    {
       //and instantiate the printRun.
       printRun = new gridIntegerField();
    }    
}
```